# Call javascript everytime the while loop runs to give a unique time from database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

Sorry for bottering again, i have another issue with javascript

This is the code for time counter from an mysql database table:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>        
        function cronometru(timp_ramas) {
            Ore = Math.floor(timp_ramas / 3600);
            minute = Math.floor((timp_ramas - Ore * 3600) / 60);
            secunde = timp_ramas - minute * 60 - Ore * 3600;
            if (Ore < 10){ Ore = "0"+ Ore; }
            if (minute < 10){ minute = "0" + minute; }
            if (secunde < 10){ secunde = "0" + secunde; }
            if (timp_ramas > 0) {

                timp_ramas--;
                document.getElementById("timp").innerHTML = Ore + ':' + minute + ':' + secunde;
                //document.getElementById("cumpara").innerHTML ="<br><a href='piata.php?cumpara=<?php echo $id_functie; ?>'>Cumpara</a>";

                setTimeout("cronometru("+timp_ramas+")", 1000);

            } else {
                document.getElementById("timp").innerHTML = "[Licitatia s-a terminat]";
            //  document.getElementById("cumpara").innerHTML = "[Nu mai poti cumpara]";

            }
        }
</script>
```

Then in php i call this script in an while function into a table form

```
while($informatie = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{   
   $timp_ramas = $informatie['data_limita'] - time();

   //........................................

   echo " <td width='40%' align='justify'>
        Pret : ".$informatie['obiect_pret']." 
        <br />
        Timp ramas : <span id='timp'> "; 

   echo " <script type='text/javascript'> cronometru(".$timp_ramas.") </script></span> ";
   if ($informatie['obiect_cantitate'] > 1) 
       echo "<br>Cantitate disponibila: ".$informatie['obiect_cantitate']." ";
   if ($informatie['data_limita'] > 1) 
       echo "<br><a href='piata.php?cumpara=".$informatie['id']."'>Cumpara</a>";

   echo "</td>";
}
```

I dont understand why if I have 3 rows each with one with different information from the database only first accesses the javascript.
The other rows works perfect, they retrive all the info from the db, but this one doesent want to show the timer( countdown) for each row. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code I wrote for my auction site. It has live countdowns for each item listed. I'm guessing you're making the same sort of thing. Look over the code and feel free to use it. It should get you on the right path anyway.

```
function countdown(x,t,b,i) {
var days = Math.floor(t / 60 / 60 / 24);
var hours = Math.floor([t - (days * 86400)] / 60 / 60 );
var minutes = Math.floor([t - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600)] / 60 );
var seconds = [t - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)];
if ( seconds == 1 ){
secondslabel = " Second"}
else {
secondslabel = " Seconds"}
if ( minutes == 1 ){
minuteslabel = " Minute "}
else {
minuteslabel = " Minutes "}
if ( hours == 1 ){
hourslabel = " Hour "}
else {
hourslabel = " Hours "}
if ( days == 1 ){
dayslabel = " Day "}
else {
dayslabel = " Days "}

if ( days == 0 && hours == 0 && minutes == 0){
document.getElementById(x).value=seconds + secondslabel;
document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = '#E19B9B';
}
else if ( days == 0 && hours == 0){
document.getElementById(x).value=minutes + minuteslabel + seconds + secondslabel;
document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = '#E19B9B';
}
else if ( days == 0){
document.getElementById(x).value=hours + hourslabel + minutes + minuteslabel;
document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = '#9BE1A0';
}
else {
if(document.getElementById(x)){
document.getElementById(x).value=days + dayslabel + hours + hourslabel;
document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = '#9BE1A0';
}
}
if ( t < 0 ){
document.getElementById(x).value='Ended';
document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
document.getElementById(b).value='Ended';
clearInterval (i);
}
}
```

Comment: i tried to use your code but when i integrated in my php , it doesnt work, i have the same problem, only on the first row appears the timer

Comment: someone knows how to deal with this problem?